# Excel: Comparison evaluates to TRUE, VLOOKUP produces #N/A

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

Excel experts, what am I missing here? Why is the formula evaluating to #N/A in cell C1? All cells are formatted as text

[image: Values]

[image: Formulas]

Actual value in A1: 1~3104641~A~ ~0000252415~BLUE SYCAM00001

Actual value in B1: 1~3104641~A~ ~0000252415~BLUE SYCAM00001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vlookup doesn't like the single tilde(~). You need to double it with this formula:

```
    =VLOOKUP(SUBSTITUTE(B1,"~","~~"),A1,1,0)
```

Comment: You're awesome. Thank you for saving me the hours of deepening the forehead-shaped dent in my desk.